# send data to function in javascript using jquery and asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net

could you please help me and tell me how can I send the href to the data in that code:

```
$(".ad-gallery").on("click", ".ad-image", function () {
    $.fancybox({

        href: $(this).find("img").attr("src"), //here is the value i want to send
        titlePosition: 'outside',
        title: $(this).text(),
        'beforeShow': function () {
            var content = $('.fancybox-inner');  // for v2.x use : var content = $('.fancybox-inner');
            $('.fancybox-wrap').append('<div class="fancy_print"></div>'); // for v2.x use : $('.fancybox-wrap').append(...
            $('.fancy_print').bind("click", function () {

                var retVal = confirm("Are you sure you want to order it?");
                if (retVal == true) {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "WebForm1.aspx/coucou",
                            data: "{}",//$titre.serialize(),// and i want to give the value inside that data
```

Thanks

Comment: Where is the rest of the code?

Comment: well, the rest are only parenthesis, nothing important.
I I only want to know how can I send the value from one function to another.
I'm usinf fancybox2 for jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a variable inside outer function.

```
$(".ad-gallery").on("click", ".ad-image", function () {
    var $this = $(this),
       href = $this.find("img").attr("src");
    $.fancybox({
        href: href, //accessible here
        titlePosition: 'outside',
        title: $this.text(),
        'beforeShow': function () {
            //You can use href here
            var content = $('.fancybox-inner');  // for v2.x use : var content = $('.fancybox-inner');
            $('.fancybox-wrap').append('<div class="fancy_print"></div>'); // for v2.x use : $('.fancybox-wrap').append(...
            $('.fancy_print').bind("click", function () {
                //And here

                var retVal = confirm("Are you sure you want to order it?");
                if (retVal == true) {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "WebForm1.aspx/coucou",
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            dataType: "json",
                            data: '{"href":"'+ href +'"}'
```

[Scope and closures](http://robertnyman.com/2008/10/09/explaining-javascript-scope-and-closures/)

Comment: Hi yury,
you're right, i can use the href variable, but now the thread doesn't reach the C# method

Comment: Hmm, haven't code .net for ages. :) As far as I know you need to send params to web method like this: `data: '{param1:"value1", param2:"value2", etc}'`. Names should match to method param names. `coucou(String param1, String param2) ...`

Comment: I have updated code. Explicitly set dataType and contentType.